# Meteor - calling serverside methods from client

Tags: meteor

Are Meteor.methods they only way to call server-side functions from the client?

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods

the docs don't make it clear that they are they only way, but the fact that they exist seems to imply they are the only way. What is their purpose?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to communicate back and forth between the server and client in Meteor :

- Using `Meteor.methods` to perform Remote Method Invokation on the server, these calls are initiated by the client, ask for a computation to be performed on the server and receive a result.
- Using the Pub/Sub mechanism, the server publishes a set of data and the client is subscribing to a subset of this data, being notified in real-time of data-updates taking place in the server and thus receiving modifications.
- Using plain old HTTP requests with the HTTP module.

So `Meteor.methods` are not the only way to execute some code on the server upon a client request.

Their purpose is usually to update the database by providing new values for server-side collections, as a matter of fact, client-side collection inserts and updates are implemented as `Meteor.methods`.

The Pub/Sub mechanism is used to propagate DB updates to every connected client and to make sure they receive only the minimal subset they need.

The HTTP communication is used by the server to send the initial source code (HTML/JS/CSS) of the app on load time as well as performing standard operations such as requesting and downloading a file.